# AWS Cognito JWT vs URL Path Parameters for Multi Tenant ID in a serverless environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant

I'm building a serverless application that's multi-tenant. It's using AWS API Gateway to feed requests through to a Lambda service for data update and retrieval, and authenticating users through AWS Cognito.

However, I'm unsure of the best practice to provide my Lambda function with appropriate tenant and user information to make requests and limit data access between tenants. An example request would be to POST a new entity within the database that requires the tenant id as a primary key, or requesting all entities under a tenant in a GET request. It's very clear here that a user under one tenant should have no access to a user under another, and so the tenant id must be verified.So far I've identified three options.

- Pass the tenant id as a URL path, for instance '*[www.example.com/{tenantid}/user/{userid}/update*'](http://www.example.com/%7Btenantid%7D/user/%7Buserid%7D/update*%27). This tenant id must then be verified by checking the user custom attributes in Cognito match the tenant id provided within the URL path.
- Pass the Cognito JWT ID token with custom claims that are processed directly by the Lambda function. This would mean retrieving these claims directly from the JWT using a decoding function to find 'tenant' : 'custom:tenantid'.
- Pass the JWT Access token to the Lambda function and use a Cognito service call to authenticate the token and retrieve the appropriate attributes. This would mean requesting Cognito, my identity provider, to provide the tenant id which is resolved to a custom attribute.

All options provide a similar result but I can find very little information comparing each method to the other. Is there a clear winner in this situation?

Comment: explore x-api-key, which can be taken as standard http request header , you can have rate limiting, access control with x-api-key while using AWS  API Gateway, out of he box. May be you can use x-api key as custom claim in your JWTs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html

Comment: Thanks very much for looking at this. I've had a look at API Keys and I'm not sure they satisfy what I'll need. I may however use them to provide additional security access. 

I have multiple ways of retrieving the tenant id from my user pool for use in the Lambda function associated to the API Gateway however I'm unsure of the best approach. In a previous small scale monolithic environment I've used URL paths verified against my tenant data. However this is a larger project and I'm keen to reduce time and cost in requests for the most efficient approach.

Comment: OK. I feel, passing custom claims is better option, and you can use Cognito authorizer in API gateway for auth, and get the custom claims decoded out of the box in API integration request, so no need to write custom lambda. And since it is all managed,  need not to worry much about scaling.